# How does correlation give better model predictability?

Tags: regression, correlation, least-squares, linear

Does correlation give better model predictability.

In case of using regression models, typically OLS, how does it help with the model predictability and what are its limitations.

Any articles or other resources would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Correlation between what?